# Download files in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i need to download a file saved in an Object. Here's my class:

```
export class MyObject {
    code: string;
    name: string;
    files: File[];

    constructor() { }
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let file of myObject.files">      
        <button (click)="download(file)"></button>
</li>
```

component.ts

```
export class MyComponent{
    myObject = new MyObject();
    constructor(){
        myObject.files = [..] // here I upload my files in array
    }

    download(file){
        // i have tried:
        // const link = document.createElement('a');
        // link.download = file.name;
        // link.href = file;
        // link.click();
    }
}
```

I have tried with that download function, but when i hit the download button, in the chrome's download bar i have just a failed download "no file".
How can I fix that?

Comment: is this a remote file with a url or a local File object? the methods are different

Comment: What are the arguments you call `download` with? Please post complete code.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović the argument file is a File from class MyObject.

Comment: @bryan60 it's a local file